# How to set TLS Cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 on Windows 2016

Tags: encryption, websphere, ibm-mq, tls1.2, windows-server

I want to enable TLS Cipher `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` on Windows 2016 to test IBM MQ client connectivity. It seems this exact name is not available on Windows and the equivalent is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` as mentioned on following page:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1607`

Shall I enable the equivalent cipher or is there a way to enable the exact one I mentioned above?

I actually tried to enable using `Enable-TlsCipherSuite` command in Powershell but IBM MQ client didn't connect. So I am not sure if this is something that can be enabled using Powershell or shall I ask Infrastructure guys to apply Windows Group policy?

Comment: What MQ client are you using? is it MQ .NET? You may want read this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=client-cipherspec-support-managed-net

Comment: I am using 9.1 and already able to connect using unmanaged .Net code. Now trying luck with managed .Net code.

Comment: Okay - Have you seen this one as well https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=client-configuring-tls-managed-mq-net ? I would also suggest you to use the latest MQ 9.3 .NET client.

Comment: You might need a different certificate for both cipher suites. The RSA_ ciphersuite uses RSA decryption to authenticate and establish keys while the ECDHE_RSA uses signature generation only for entity authentication.